# showing newly added rows after submit if error comes

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am using this Javascript to add rows in table `preq` which already contains 4 rows. The problem is that when I add rows using this Javascript  rows are added properly on form, but if some error comes on form, and if form is reloaded than this newly added rows are not visible and I also want entered text within rows to be visible
[image]

`javascript`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var counter = 5;
            function addrow()
            {
                if (counter > 10)
                {
                    alert("Only 10 Kind of Works are allowed");
                return false;
                }
            $('#preq > tbody:last').append('<tr><td><input title="Enter Kind Of work" readonly="readonly" onclick="if(this.value!=\'\'){this.value=\'\';opendrop();}else{opendrop();}" id="other_work' + counter + '" name="other_work' + counter + '" type="text" size="30" onclick="opendrop()" <?php if (isset($errors)) { echo 'value="'.htmlentities(@$_POST['other_work' + counter + '']).'"'; } ?>></td><td><input name="client_name' + counter + '" type="text" id="client_name' + counter + '" size="40"/></td><td><input name="firm_name' + counter + '" type="text" id="firm_name' + counter + '" size="40"/></td></tr>');
                counter++;
            }
            </script>
```

html code

```
<table align="left" id="preq" style="display: none;">
                <tr>
                                </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                    <th align="left"><label id="Label1"> Kind of Work </label></th>
                                    <th align="left"><label id="Label1"> Name Of The Client </label></th>
                                    <th align="left"><label id="Label1">Name of Firm / Organisation </label></th>
                                    </tr>
            <tbody>

            <!--4 rows alredy present here-->
            </tbody>
    <tr><td colspan="3"><input type="button" class="button" value="Add Kind of Work" onclick="addrow()"/></td></tr>

            </table>
```

Comment: Look into the difference between *server-side programming language* (PHP) and *client-side programming language* (JavaScript).

Answer (score 1):

If you want the newly added rows to persist even after reloading form then you need to save it to the database otherwise every time the page is reloaded the data will be lost.

Comment: it is an submit form ,so i want newly added rows to persist if some error comes on form after submit button clicked

Answer (score 0):

Try add `else`, so, the rows to be added only if no error (which is alerted on `if()`).

```
if (counter > 10) {
  alert("Only 10 Kind of Works are allowed");
  return false;
} else {
  $('#preq > tbody:last').append('<tr><td><input title="Enter Kind Of work" readonly="readonly" onclick="if(this.value!=\'\'){this.value=\'\';opendrop();}else{opendrop();}" id="other_work' + counter + '" name="other_work' + counter + '" type="text" size="30" onclick="opendrop()" <?php if (isset($errors)) { echo 'value="'.htmlentities(@$_POST['other_work' + counter + '']).'"'; } ?>></td><td><input name="client_name' + counter + '" type="text" id="client_name' + counter + '" size="40"/></td><td><input name="firm_name' + counter + '" type="text" id="firm_name' + counter + '" size="40"/></td></tr>');
  counter++;
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Newly added rows are not yet visible on form reload ,if error comes on form